# How to get a reference to a tag's parent?

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker

I the scenario of nested custom tags; ie:

```
<ss:mytag>
    <ss:othertag />
    <ss:othertag />
</ss:mytag>
```

From within the freemarker template of othertag, how do I get a handle on the wrapping mytag parent?

My goal here is to see if the current tag is the first child of it's parent. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use global variables for that. Like you do `<#global mylib_othertagCnt = 0>` in `mytag`, and `<#global mylib_othertagCnt = mylib_othertagCnt + 1>` and then `<#if mylib_othertagCnt == 1>...</#if>` in `othertag`.

Comment: The logic is sound, but when I try this it appears the global variable is not available in othertag (Expression mylib_othertagCnt is undefined) is there a way to place the variable into the valuestack then findValue it from othertag?

Comment: Actually, this method won't work for me since I will need to support dynamic depth nesting.

Comment: Ended up finding a work around outside of free marker. Still interested on how to do this.

Comment: If you set it with `#global` before reading it, it should be available in `othertag`. I'm not sure what went wrong there.

Comment: What exactly is dynamic depth nesting? Anyway, supporting this kind of thing, where child directives communicate with the parent, is a known deficiency... and currently the solution is using globals. Of course, that global can be some POJO that stores some more intricate data structure, like `List` of relevant parent data objects, etc.